# Subquery returned more than 1 value

Tags: sql-server, trigger

In my database I have two tables: `projects` and `comp_types`. When a new project is created a trigger is hit which inserts a concatenated value in a column in the `projects` table.

A fully working [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/f7dc8/1/1).
Please run this and you will see, it works.

However when I try to run it in SQL Server I receive the following error:

> Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.

Screenshot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/38rKV.jpg

All tables in the SQL Server are fresh, with no data (just like the fiddle).
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: what values are you trying to insert when it fails ? I looked at the fiddle and it works OK.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I'm trying to insert the exact same as the fiddle.

Comment: I am not getting any errors. Can you post a screenshot with the error ?

Comment: Check this: `SELECT comp_type FROM comp_types WHERE comp_type_id = comp_type_id` you should be equaling to some value on the projs table as this will return all values in comp_types

Comment: Image has been added.

Comment: The error appears when the `comp_types` has more than 1 row.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your trigger has no `WHERE` clause, does not correlate to the row(s) that were just inserted, and doesn't handle the case where multiple rows might be inserted in a single operation (unlike some platforms, in SQL Server a trigger fires per statement, not per row). So it will work exactly once: when you insert the very first row into the `projects` table. Try the following instead:

```
CREATE TRIGGER dbo.create_proid -- please always use schema prefix
ON dbo.projects 
FOR INSERT
AS
BEGIN
  SET NOCOUNT ON;

  UPDATE p
    SET pro_id = CONVERT(VARCHAR(20), c.comp_type)
      + '-' 
      + RIGHT('00000' + CONVERT(NVARCHAR(20), i.client_id), 
        CASE WHEN i.client_id < 100000 THEN 5 ELSE 6 END)
      + '-' 
      + RIGHT('00000' + CONVERT(NVARCHAR(20), i.id), 
        CASE WHEN i.id < 100000 THEN 5 ELSE 6 END)
  FROM dbo.projects AS p
  INNER JOIN inserted AS i 
  ON p.id = i.id
  INNER JOIN dbo.comp_types AS c
  ON p.comp_type_id = c.comp_type_id;
END
```

Not sure why you're storing the `pro_id` value when you can determine it at runtime. Do you also have an update trigger that maintains it when the `comp_type_id` changes? What if a `comp_type` is deleted?

Also [please always use schema prefix](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/11/bad-habits-to-kick-avoiding-the-schema-prefix) and [don't convert to `NVARCHAR` without specifying a length](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/09/bad-habits-to-kick-declaring-varchar-without-length). And why are you using the `text` data type? This has been deprecated for ages - you should be using `NVARCHAR(MAX)` or `VARCHAR(MAX)` *only if* these names and descriptions will really exceed 4000/8000 characters (highly unlikely from the naming).

Comment: Thank you very much! I thought the trigger is per row, but this clears it up a lot. To answer your questions: I thought not specifying a length for `nvarchar` will auto-assign it to 30, did not know about the size of 1. The only reason text is being used is due to the unknown possible lengths of the strings (especially `pro_descpt`; product description).

Comment: @BenZ will product description really potentially exceed 8000 characters (or 4000 if you need Unicode support)? And if you need Unicode support (implied by the data type of `pro_id`), why is comp_type `text` and not `ntext`?

Comment: There are no triggers yet for updates in the `comp_types` table, but these will be added. `pro_id` is being stored because this is how the table initially was created, now several other systems depend on this table which expect it to be stored. Our IT-team finds it easier to keep the table this way than to fix the older systems. Unicode support is there due to our database "administrator"'s fear of the future, but is not being used/needed right now.

Comment: Ok, then at the very least the requirements should match. You shouldn't have some columns with Unicode support and some without...

Comment: Thank you. That makes perfect sense, and will be fixed. As you can see I am fairly new to DBA; just started working for a company where the 'production server = test server'. As you can imagine such is not the best learning environment.

Comment: No, sounds like trial by fire to me.

Comment: @BenZ sometimes that can be a great environment to learn as you have no choice but to learn fast. :)